# I cannot load a proper google map in Jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsfiddle

I am trying to get [this Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpcroke/5jejLq4p/1/) to work. I added the appropriate external google map API call. I cannot figure out why I can not get any map to load. I tried cutting and pasting five other jsfiddle projects and none would load. I have the following as an "external resource"

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
```

I went to my google developers console and added my jsfiddle url. I have no idea what's going on.

To be exact, I copied working examples such as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingstiff/rsp22/), [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rasg/va4eq/) and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/8mQ6G/) with no luck. All other elements except the map work so I am obviously not communicating with the API correctly. From the Javascript console I get this error:

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

Comment: I may be unsure, but I do not believe that google allows you to add your API key to another domain.

Comment: @Bonatti I guess I'm confused then because how do I get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/

Comment: See the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>` This is loading the map, note the lack of API key. Yours should appear as `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?[YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE">`. Finally, if all you need is testing, then change the domain from `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api` to `maps.google.com/maps/api/`

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem. Plus, I don't think you actually need to use the API key anyways but I could be wrong.

Comment: No. What I meant was, you have to deliberately inform Google on all domains you are intending to use their resources. There is a "testing/production" api (the `maps.google.com/maps/api/` one) that does not need an API key, the rest does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your JSFiddle - after looking at the developer's console in my browser, I noticed the error message mentioning you've imported the Google Maps API too many times.

I can't seem to resolve this issue on your fiddle, but after importing your code into CodePen, adding the Google API resource through the UI and removing the following line of code, it worked fine:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

The link to my CodePen is here:
http://codepen.io/jarodsmk/pen/beBXBb

Please note that with external resources in online editors like CodePen and JSFiddle, you only need to import them once, either in your code or through the UI of the editor :)

In the actual implementation of your application, you'll need to import it.

Comment: I moved over to codepen and sure enough - worked fine. Not sure what went wrong with JSFiddle. Thanks!